# Including a file in open card

Tags: opencart

I have created a ControllerModule in opencart. I want to include a SMS.php file which contains a class of SMS-API. How should I include this file and where is the proper place to put this file in the project? I'm a too newbie to opencart.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't for learning stuff from beginning. You should start somewhere (e.g. reading through this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478995/how-to-become-an-opencart-guru) and try implement it for Yourself.

Comment: @Mostafa, Since this question is specific to OpenCart, you can try to ask it on http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77558/opencart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In index.php file after `require_once($vqmod->modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/cart.php'));` add:

```
 require_once($vqmod->modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/sms.php'));
```

Afer `$registry->set('cart', new Cart($registry));` add

```
 //Sms library
 $registry->set('sms', new Sms($registry));  //where Sms is your class name
```

Once these changes are done you can call the class functions like      `$this->sms->getSmsInfo();`

Have a nice day !!